# Google Chrome didn't render DOM in inactive mode?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following selenium script running in google chrome/chromedriver 90 in macOS, here is my finding: when running the script and make the chrome process active all the time, it works as my expectation. When running the script and switch to other unrelated process, just let the attaching chrome process alive in the inactive (not hidden) process state, it breaks!

```py
the_element = self.waiter.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="channel-area"]')))

try:
    the_element.click()
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception(e)
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Exception:

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="channel-area">...</div> is not clickable at point (380, 623). Other element would receive the click: <div class="leave-active" style="z-index: 1034;"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

I think a web browser shouldn't expose the process state to a website/web developer, right? Is it a user state leak? Or are there any magic environment chrome flags to disable it?

BTW, I've confirmed that firefox/firefox-esr 86 couldn't repro this issue, no custom configurations there.

Answer (score 0):

Is it in viewPort ?

try this :

```
the_element = self.waiter.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='channel-area']")))
try:
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(the_element).click().perform()
except Exception as e:
   logger.exception(e)
   import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

[Reference link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html)

Comment: `the_element` is just a common div under a `form`, the above code doesn't work with no exception info throw, its click event didn't trigger, either, in inactive mode. But it works in normal process state, too.

Comment: How do you interact with that div ? Do you have to perform any mouse scrolling ?

Comment: In the active foreground state, no, just wait for it happens.